# Модификация запуска команды bash

Tags: linux, bash

Есть функция, которая запускает переданную в нее команду

```
function run() {
    OLD_PWD=`pwd`

    cd `dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"`/..

    if "$@"
    then
        echo "GOOD"
        cd ${OLD_PWD}
    else
        colorecho 1 "Command <$@> failed ... exiting"
        cd ${OLD_PWD}
        exit 1
    fi
}
```

Необходимо вставить в запуск этой команды утилиту time, то есть я пишу `run mkdir -p /some/thing/dir`, а под капотом вызывается `/usr/bin/time -f "%C %E" mkdir -p /some/thing/dir`, подскажите как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно как-то так:

```
function run() {
     #...
     /usr/bin/time -f "%C %E" "$@"
     #...
}
```

Конечно, GNU'тый `time` должен быть установлен.

Кроме этого вместо `OLD_PWD` я бы советовал использовать `pushd`/`popd` или subshell.

Comment: не понял как это вставить в условие, не могли бы пример показать на основе моего кода, а то я вставляю это и ловлю ошибку `./scripts/run.sh: line 29: /usr/bin/time -f "%C %E" @: No such file or directory`

Comment: @shotInLeg, какое условие?... да, `$` в комманде я пропустил...

Comment: мне нужно проверить код завершения этого процесса

Comment: @shotInLeg, можно прям так подставить в `if`, а можно поставить перед if'ом, а потом `$?` сравнить с нулём...

Answer (score 0):

Так, наверное:

```
function run() {
    OLD_PWD=`pwd`

    TIME = `/some/thing/dir`

    cd `dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"`/..

    run mkdir -p ${TIME}

    if "$@"
    then
        echo "GOOD"
        cd ${OLD_PWD}
    else
        colorecho 1 "Command <$@> failed ... exiting"
        cd ${OLD_PWD}
        exit 1
    fi
}
```

Comment: задача не запустить что-то преред выполнением команды, а посчитать время работы переданной команды. 
`run ls -l` -> выполяет `ls -l`, а я хочу чтобы `run ls -l` выполнял `/usr/bin/time -f "%C %E" ls -l`

Answer (score 0):

Не настаиваю, но это работает.

```
run () {
        local retv
        pushd "$(pwd)" >/dev/null
        cd "${BASH_SOURCE[0]%/*}"
        source <(cat <<CODE
        /usr/bin/time -f '%C %E' $@
        retv=$?
CODE
        )
        popd >/dev/null
        (( retv )) && \
                {
                        colorecho 1 "Command <<$@>> failed ... exiting" >&2
                        exit $retv
                } || echo 'GOOD' >&2

        return 0
}

run find /etc -type f -name '*tab' -exec cat {} '\;' '2>/dev/null'
```